# how to include a template with parameters in EJS?

Tags: ejs

As a real beginner in EJS, I have two charts in my html page, so I want to use my partial twice:

```
<% include partials/spider-chart.ejs %>
```

But I need to pass some parameters inside the ejs to differentiate between graphs.

What is the best way?

Comment: did you check the Zubair's answer? maybe you should reconsider which one is the accepted one.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

@Naeem Shaikh solution works.
Though `include` also gives you more intuitive way of including a partial template and also passing context variables to that as found in [documention section of ejs](http://ejs.co/#docs).

```
<ul>
  <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
      <%- include('user/show', {user: user}); %>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: if i try this,         

`
<div>
 <%- include folder/index , {user: user} %>
</div>
`
 i get

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/(folder/index.ejs'`

Comment: You need to wrap parameters in a parenthesis. `<div> <%- include ('folder/index' , {user: user}); %> </div>`

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. The other way using a global variable has the smell of sphagetti code. It lacks encapsulation and relies on assumptions (e.g. that the var data is not used for anything else)

Comment: I am getting "cannot find include include file" error :( .    `<%- include ('partials/navbar.ejs' , if(locals.login && login) {login:true }); %>`

Comment: maybe I'm late for the party, but the only way I found to get a `foreach` work with `include` template is by using `<% include user/show %>` as read [here](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes)

Comment: If you are getting an error doing `include (filename, data)`, remember to remove the space between `include` and the bracket `(`: `include(filename, data)`

Comment: While not applicable to the original question, note that if you do not pass a second argument to `include` then you get the same variables as in the initial file (knowing this tidbit would have saved me some searching).

Answer (score 34):

I think you want to render two different charts using same *partial* ejs template, just by providing different data(within the main ejs file).

You can just define a variable, which will be assigned to the `data`, which the first chart will use, than include the `chart.ejs` file, again change the `data`, and include the partial ejs file(chart.ejs) again, so now you have two files which can use same variable(data), but can plot different chart based on  value assigned to `data`.

**For Example:**

```
<% var data= 'data to be used by first chart(parameter)'; %>
<% include partials/spider-chart.ejs %>

// re-initializing data for second chart
<% data= 'data to be used by second chart(parameter)'; %>
<% include partials/spider-chart.ejs %>
```

where your `spider-chart.ejs` file could be something which will use `data`

**spider-chart.ejs**

```
    <li>
        <%= data %> // just an example
    </li>
```

here, as you use data, the data variable accessed by both charts will be different because you are reassigning values for data before every chart.

Answer (score 16):

You can pass single as well as multiple data here is how to do it

> **In render funtions**

We can pass multiple data as an object like this

```js
app.get("/account", function(req, res) {
  res.render("account", {
    name: 'Jon Snow',
    age: 35
  });
});
```

And then can access the data inside `account` using ejs simple template tags like this

`<h2> hello  <%= name %>  </h2>
 <p> your age is <%= age %> </p>`

> **In Partial views**

Pass the data like this

```js
<%- include('partials/logout', {name='triyon'}) %>
```

And access it like we did above

`<h2> logged out  <%= name %>  </h2>`

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `{name='triyon'}` should be `{name:'triyon'}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best workaround by just passing the view file name as a context while rendering the base ejs file.

/base.ejs:

```
<html>
    <%- include(content) %>
</html>
```

/extra.ejs:

```
<div> some content which is to be added in base ejs file </div>
```

/controller.js:

```
res.render('base', { content: 'extra' })
```