# How to include an ejs with some parameters?

Tags: express, ejs

I have a file, let's say `index.ejs` which I render using express this way:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {
     projectName: req.params.name
}
```

Inside this ejs file, I include another file, let's say `base.ejs`.
I'm trying to pass the variable projectName to `base.ejs`.
I have tried the following approaches:

```
<%- include("path/to/base.ejs", {projectName: projectName})" %>
<%- include("path/to/base.ejs", {projectName: <%=projectName%>})" %>
<%- include("path/to/base.ejs", {projectName: '<%=projectName%>'})" %>
```

None of them seem to work. 
This is a similar answer I found [how to include a template with parameters in EJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196562/how-to-include-a-template-with-parameters-in-ejs) but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Try using `<%= projectName %>` in your `base.ejs` file wherever you want to use it, I don't think you need to pass it as `{projectName: projectName}` as you have been trying

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. There was no need to pass it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'll add it as an answer so that if others run into the same issue it is clear to see the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to pass the variable to the include statement as you have been doing, just use the variable in your `base.ejs` file as follows

```
<%= projectName %>
```

When using the include statement you can simply declare

```
<% include path/to/base %>
```